# cURL send JSON and PDF file

Tags: python, json, pdf, curl, flask

I have this cURL command to speak with my API:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"sid":"01234567","text":"TEST","tlf":"123456","ctc":"123456","opr":"XYZ","fbm":"email@email.com","flag":"XYZ","product":"XYZ"}' http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/todo/api/v1.0/tasks
```

Which works perfectly, here the response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 24
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.3 Python/2.6.6
Date: Wed, 07 Jun 2017 10:03:00 GMT
```

Now I want to send a pdf file in that same command.

I figured I add:

```
"file":"/var/www/html/olotool/API/attachments/pdf-test.pdf"
```

at the end but it gets saved as a string instead of a document.

How can I add this in one command?

UPDATE:

```
"file":"$(base64 ~/attachments/pdf-test.pdf)"
```

Changes the outcome into `<type 'file'>` it's still a string but at least it's content is not `(base64 ~/attachments/pdf-test.pdf)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
curl -i -F data='{"sid":"0123456","text":"TEST","tlf":"13245679","ctc":"123456","opr":"XXX","fbm":"mail@mail.com","flag":"XYZ","product":"XYZ"}' -F 'file=@/var/www/html/olotool/API/testpdf/test.pdf' http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/todo/api/v1.0/tasks
```

On the API instead of using `request.json` you use `request.form` then convert `data`to json with `json.loads(data)`.

For the file, you need to use `request.file['files']` and dont forget to encode files like pdf's or word docs to base64 if you want to import them to MySQL with `file.read().encode("base64")`

Answer (score -2):

curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "https://wsmipres.sispro.gov.co/WSMIPRESNOPBS/api/PrescripcionPaciente/900204617/2020-06-19/C68A900A-9FB9-46CB-B24B-4AB56E078600/CC/1098798857"

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are about to answer an old question (this one is over 3 years old) that already has an accepted answer (that is the case here) please ask yourself: Do I really have a substantial improvement to offer? If not, consider refraining from answering. Also, consider adding explanations, and proper formatting (markdown).